# Talend (7.0.1) - Cannot modify mapred.job.name at runtime

Tags: hive, talend

I am having some trouble running a simple tHiveCreateTable job in Talend OS for Big Data ([Print of the job where I am getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMNRQ.png)). 
The Hive connection is fine and the job worked until Ranger was activated in the cluster.

After ranger, I started getting the following log:

```
   [statistics] connecting to socket on port 3345
   [statistics] connected
   Error while processing statement: Cannot modify mapred.job.name at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime
   [statistics] disconnected
```

This error occurs either using Tez or MapReduce for the job, throwing an exception in the following line of the automatically generated code:

```
    // For MapReduce Mode
    stmt_tHiveCreateTable_1.execute("set mapred.job.name=" + queryIdentifier);
```

Do you know any solution or workarround for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found a way to get arround this issue looking for similar errors. The workarround is to configure in the hive-site.xml the property hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist which is used as the name suggestes to create a whitelist of configurations so they can be  modified at runtime.

Comment: hi @ssobreiro, Could you please let me know, if these properties can be set in Advanced Settings of tHiveConnection ? I tried but it seems to be not working

Comment: Hi @user1023627. The whitelist property must be configured in hive-site.xml. It's the Hive service that will allow or refuse mapred update at runtime. And, as far as I know, it's useless to configure the mapred property in tHiveConnection's advanved properties because Talend will try to update the value either way (please, someone correct me on this if I am wrong :) ).

Comment: Thanks @ssobreiro. Could you please let me know, the property name and details which i need to add to hive-site.xml

Comment: Hi @user1023627. You can just add a property named "hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist" (if it does not yet exists). For the value use, for instance, the names of the properties you need to whitelist separated by "|" (a pipe). This worked for me when I was dealing with this problem.     Use for instance: <property>
     <name>hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append</name>
    <value>mapred.job.name|tez\.queue\.name|my\.third\.property</value>
</property>      Anyway... I believe that there should be a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to disable changing mapreduce.job.name and hive.query.name at runtime by Talend7 jobs.

Edit the file

```
{talend_install_dir}/plugins/org.talend.designer.components.localprovider_7.1.1.20181026_1147/components/templates/Hive/SetQueryName.javajet
```

and comment out lines 6 and 11 like that:

```
// stmt_<%=cid %>.execute("set mapred.job.name=" + queryIdentifier_<%=cid %>);
// stmt_<%=cid %>.execute("set hive.query.name=" + queryIdentifier_<%=cid %>);
```

It solved this issue for me.