# tHiveCreateTable component gives "org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException" exception

Tags: hadoop, hive, talend

I have a Talend Big Data job where I am trying to connect to Hive and create a table. Hive connect works fine. But tHiveCreate table gives the below exception.

```
Exception in component tHiveCreateTable_1 (Test)
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: Cannot modify mapred.job.name at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccess(Utils.java:258)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.verifySuccessWithInfo(Utils.java:244)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:247)
    at local_project.test_0_1.Test.tHiveCreateTable_1Process(Test.java:643)
    at local_project.test_0_1.Test.tHiveConnection_1Process(Test.java:498)
    at local_project.test_0_1.Test.runJobInTOS(Test.java:948)
    at local_project.test_0_1.Test.main(Test.java:799)
Caused by: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: Cannot modify mapred.job.name at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:324)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.HiveCommandOperation.runInternal(HiveCommandOperation.java:108)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.run(Operation.java:264)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:479)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:466)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:315)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:509)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1377)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement.getResult(TCLIService.java:1362)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Earlier, the tHiveConnection was failing with same error. As per one of the older posts, I unchecked the Hadoop propeties from the tHiveConnect component and it worked fine. The similar properties are not available in the tHiveCreateTable component as I am using the tHiveConnection to provide connection details to tHiveCreateTable component.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem as [Talend (7.0.1) - Cannot modify mapred.job.name at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50176579/talend-7-0-1-cannot-modify-mapred-job-name-at-runtime). Try to fix property hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist

Comment: Could you please advise what should be the value for this property.

Comment: Thanks @Harold. With your answer and some more research, I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue.
Added a property to custom hive site in Ambari as:
hive.security.authorization.sqlstd.confwhitelist.append with values 
mapred.job.name|mapred.child.env|query.invoker|hive.query.name

The issue got fixed.